# How is this derivation possible in a context-free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Suppose we have the rules:

$R \rightarrow XRX | S$

$S \rightarrow aTb | bTa$

$T \rightarrow XTX | X | \epsilon$

$X \rightarrow a | b$.

My textbook says that $T \stackrel{*}\implies T$ is possible. Could this be a mistake because I am almost certain this cannot be. Or else I must not be understanding correctly.

Start with $T$. We have three choices

$T \implies XTX$. But now that we have $X$ involved, we will have $a's$ and/or $b's$ involved.

$T \implies X$. Again we will have $a$ or $b$ involved.

$T \implies \epsilon$. But $\epsilon \not= T$.

This is exercise 2.3 (i) in Michael Sipser's Theory of Computation 3rd edition (not homework)

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are the only terminals, right (well and the empty string, $\varepsilon$)?

Comment: That is correct, sorry I did not state that, but the problem does not state it either.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814904/what-are-these-arrow-operators-in-context-free-grammar I think the key is the empty string.  A valid sentence can be nothing, which $T$ produces with $0$ or more productions of $T \rightarrow \varepsilon$ (in fact, it could be as many $T \rightarrow \varepsilon$'s as you like).

Comment: I understand now. My book states that $u \implies v$ if $u = v$. Hence $T \implies T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is notation problem:

- The star in $X\stackrel{*}\Longrightarrow Y$ denotes *zero* or more steps. In other words $T \stackrel{*}\Longrightarrow T$ is true, because relation $\stackrel{*}\Longrightarrow$ is reflexive. You can think about it a bit like $\leq$ relation (depending on the grammar it might actually be a non-strict partial order).
- On the other hand, $X\stackrel{+}\Longrightarrow Y$ denotes *one* or more steps and in result $T\stackrel{+}\Longrightarrow T$ is in your case false. You can think of it a bit like the strict version $<$ (depending on the grammar it might actually be a strict partial order).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$